# prepopulated fields in django not working properly

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

```
class Theblog(models.Model):
    blog_image=models.ImageField(upload_to="home/images")
    blog_title=models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    blog_description=models.CharField(max_length=200,default="Adsoptimiser")
    blog_body=RichTextField(blank=True,null=True)
    blog_date=models.DateTimeField()
    author=models.CharField(max_length=35,default="Sunil Kumar")
    blog_meta_keywords=models.TextField(default=" ")
    blog_meta_description=models.CharField(max_length=1000,default=" ")


class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('blog_title',)}
    list_display = ('blog_title','blog_date')
admin.site.register(metaTag)
admin.site.register(Theblog,BlogAdmin)
```

i want to prepulate the slug as the value of the title how to do it i have searchand get to see some ways  i try to impliment but nothing is working for me please point out my mistake why this is happening

Comment: Is this when creating or when editing an existing entry? `prepopulated_fields` will only work when creating

Comment: when creating a new entry when i create it first i have not inserted prepopulated fields but i want to do now

Comment: it is occuring when i am creating a new entry

Comment: Check your browser's devtools console to see if there are any JS errors? Possibly some conflict with your RichTextField field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`from django.contrib import admin`

```
@admin.register(TheBlog)
class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['blog_title','blog_date']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('blog_title',)}
```

Comment: raise AlreadyRegistered(msg)
django.contrib.admin.sites.AlreadyRegistered: The model Theblog is already registered with 'home.BlogAdmin'.  it raise this issue

Comment: Thank you brother this is workinf after fixing the issue

Comment: Consider up voting the answer instead of saying thanks :)